# The requested URL /typo3/sysext/lowlevel/dbint/index.php&SET[function]=search&SET[search]=raw&SET[sword]=mailformplus was not found on this server

Tags: backend, typo3

Typo3 4.5.2
php 5.2

Steps:

1. search something from DB check module
2. open a record from results
3. click on different tabs for the record (general, plugin, extended etc.)
4. try to close the record now

it throws following error in typo3 backend

The requested URL /typo3/sysext/lowlevel/dbint/index.php&SET[function]=search&SET[search]=raw&SET[sword]=mailformplus was not found on this server.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but here's a wild guess: after index.php replace that one "&" with a "?"

Answer (score 0):

as this looks like a TYPO3 Core bug, please report such findings in the official bug tracker on [forge.typo3.org](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-core/issues).

Otherwise (almost) nobody will notice or take care.

Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce this. It always worked for me. Have you tried sth. else than I did in this [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/Bufr7FX4S)?
Have you tried another installation of TYPO3, whether this bug also occurs there?

It would be nice, if you would report the bug, if it's reproducible. Thanks

Steffen Gebert
TYPO3 Core Team Member

P.S.: As Bob explained, the & has to be replaced or prepended with an ?

Comment: Hi Steffen, the bug is reported on forge.typo3.org with video, Link is: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/26167